# overriding with instances in std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this problem:

```
struct A
{
  ... some const virtual members ...
};

struct B: A
{
  ... some const overrides ...
};

struct C
{
  C(std::initializer_list<A> const& list) // initialized with instances of B
  {
    for (auto const& a: list)
    {
      a.virtual_member_call(); // but struct B overloads do not get called
    }
  }
};
```

This happens, because instances of B are copied into instances of A. What are the workarounds (other than allocating from the heap) to get around this problem? I suppose a variadic template constructor could be one of such.

Comment: `std::initializer_list<A*>`?

Comment: That would require allocating from the heap or placement new.

Comment: No, `C{&b1, &b2, &b3, &b4, ...}`.

Comment: hehehe, good idea, but somewhat awkward. Still good idea.

Comment: If you feel awkward around naked pointers, there's also `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<A>>` and `C{std::ref(b1), std::ref(b2), std::ref(b3), ...}`, but that's just boilerplate for the above.

Comment: Was hoping to allocate temporaries from the stack and just chain them somehow together. Variadic templates it is then...

Comment: @Xeo: Unfortunately that doesn't work if you want to pass in temporaries for whatever reason, since `std::ref(T&&)` is deleted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But one can convert `&&` to `const &`, so this is not a huge problem.

Comment: @user1095108: It is if you want to mutate the "elements" of the initializer list; you need to cast the `const`ness away and it would be easy to accidentally do that to something that really was, originally, `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because of *slicing*.

`std::initializer_list<>` is not a polymorphic container, it is a simple container of values of type `A`. When constructing the list, your objects get copied. When copy-constructing an object of type `A` from an object of type `B`, slicing occurs. You will end up with an object of type `A` which is a "projection over A" of the original object of type `B` you copied from.

Consider using (smart) pointers if you want to have a *heterogeneous* initializer list of polymorphic types.

Comment: are variadic templates the only other way?

Comment: @user1095108: Variadic templates are a possibility, yes, but you can also use pointers as the value of the `initializer_list<>`, as suggested

Comment: Oh, well... I was hoping for something not requiring pointers and not requiring variadic templates (as too many of those make my code ugly).

Comment: @user1095108: I am aware you may find this answer a bit upsetting, but maybe you could consider getting more acquainted with reading code that uses templates, so that they won't look ugly any more :-)

Comment: variadic constructors work perfectly. Too bad for the syntax :)